# How would I add a String to the end of a line of a file in bash

Tags: bash

Say I have a file named output.txt. Every line in output.txt starts with a different word. How could I perform something like if any line starts with "word" then add "new word" to the end of the line?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using Perl.

```
perl -p -e'$_ .= "new word" if /^word/" output.txt > newfile.txt
```

If you want to edit the file in place you would use Perl's `-i` flag for "in place edit"

```
perl -i -p -e'$_ .= "new word" if /^word/" output.txt
```

You could also use sed or awk.

Answer (score 2):

Andy's answer is good. If you want to use `sed` you could do

```
sed 's/\(^word.*$\)/\1new word/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Even simpler: `sed '/^word/s/$/new word/' input.txt > output.txt`. This "replaces" the end of the line with "new word", but only on lines that begin with "word".

Answer (score 1):

```
while read i; do
    if [[ $i == word* ]]; then
        echo ${i}newword >> newfile
    else
        echo $i >> newfile
    fi
done < "file.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
awk '$1 == "word" {$(NF+1) = "new word"} 1' output.txt > tempfile &&
mv tempfile output.txt
```

I'm assume you don't necessarily need regex matching for the first word